# The Visual Studio command "code ." or "code filename.py" using the linux terminal does open the VS Code software but does not end the execution

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, command-line, command-line-interface

What I did/what´s happening:

1. In the Linux terminal command line: $ code .
2. VS Code opens up
3. Command in the terminal still not terminated (also after several minutes). Only after closing the VS Code program, the command finishes.

I would like to open my python file via the linux terminal and do code editing without losing the option to use the linux terminal while the VS software is running.

Update: Using the terminal on the next day, it apparently worked for some unknown reason (have not restarted anything etc. laptop was just on sleeping mode) again.

Comment: Have you tried using the ampersand token to background the process? Most shells I’m aware of support it: `code . &`

Comment: I have not tried yet, because for unknown reason the problem vanished on its own.